# Aligning unequal sized images in a Bootstrap grid

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, alignment

I'm using 3 images with unequal dimensions inside a 3 x 4 columns Bootstrap grid:

[image]

Which are messing up my layout. What I would like to achieve is this:

[image]

What is the correct way to achieve this result via CSS?

```
 <div class="row text-center">

        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3 mb-md-0">
          <div class="image-1">
           <img src="assets/img/image_1.svg" class="mb-3">                      
            <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
            <p>
              Autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae.
            </p>
          </div> 
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-md-0">
          <div class="image-2">
            <img src="assets/img/image_2.svg" class="mb-3">
            <h4>Dolor Sit Amet</h4>
            <p>
                Autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-md-0">
          <div class="image-3">
              <img src="assets/img/image_3.svg" class="mb-3">
            <h4>consetetur sadipscing</h4>
            <p>
                Autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could add a top padding on the boxes with the smallest height while preserving the box-sizing by using the box-sizing property and set it to border-box.This way the inner contents would kind of shrink to the bottom without affecting the outer layour